# Python data structure design

Tags: python, data-structures

The data structure should meet the following purpose:

- each object is unique with certain key-value pairs
- the keys and values are not predetermined and can contain any string value
- querying for objects should be fast

Example:

- `object_123({'stupid':True, 'foo':'bar', ...})`
- `structure.get({'stupid':True, 'foo':'bar', ...})` should return `object_123`

Optimally this structure is implemented with the standard python data structures available through the standard library.

How would you implement this?

Comment: @phooji: No. I just couldn't think of any could clean and good implementation of this and was looking for expert advice.

Comment: @phooji: I wondered that, too, but his other questions seem legit.

Comment: Are the objects mutable?  Can `object_123` get new keys or changed values or both?

Comment: @S.Lott: in this specific case they are immutable, but it would be interesting, how this is implemented with mutable objects?

Comment: @ahojnnes,@Kirk Strauser: Thanks -- just clarifying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of is to use sorted tuple keys:

```
def key(d): return tuple(sorted(d.items()))

x = {}
x[key({'stupid':True, 'foo':'bar', ...})] = object_123

x.get(key({'stupid':True, 'foo':'bar', ...})) => object_123
```

Another option would be to come up with your own hashing scheme for your keys (either by wrapping them in a class or just using numeric keys in the dictionary), but depending on your access pattern this may be slower.

Comment: +1, although part of me is wondering if there is a way that namedtuple might help...

Answer (score 0):

I think [SQLite](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) or is what you need. It may not be implemented with standard python structures but it's available through the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Say `object_123` is a dict, which it pretty much looks like. Your `structure` seems to be a standard dict with keys like `(('foo', 'bar'), ('stupid', True))`; in other words, `tuple(sorted(object_123.items()))` so that they're always listed in a defined order.

The reason for the defined ordering is because `dict.items()` isn't guaranteed to return a list in a given ordering. If your dictionary key is `(('foo', 'bar'), ('stupid', True))`, you don't want a false negative just because you're searching for `(('stupid', True),('foo', 'bar'))`. Sorting the values is probably the quickest way to protect against that.